# Html form not passing value to PHP POST variable

Tags: php, html, variables, post

I have a simple HTML form that i am trying to connect to php script and the values from html form are not passing to PHP variables. I have checked the PHP test file and it shows that PHP is active & installed on the XAMPP. I have also tested another php sum function script and that works fine. Please look at the script and any help will be appreciated. I get the following result when i enter any city names [See the image for results i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGLUK.jpg)

```
 <html>
 <body>
    <p>
        <H1>Enter your shipment details</H1></p>

        <form action="quotes.php" method="post">
            <label for="pickupcity">Pick up Location</label>
            <input type="text" id="pickupcity" name="pickupcity"/><br/>
            <label for="deliverycity">Delivery Location</label>
            <input type="text" id="deliverycity" name="deliverycity"/><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html

    Here is the PHP part 

    <html>
    <body>
        <h1>
            Your shipment details.
        </h1>
        <?php
            $pick= $_POST['pickupcity'];
            $delivery= $_POST['deliverycity'];

            echo 'Thanks for submitting the form.<br/>';
            echo 'Your load picks up in ' . $pick;
            echo 'and delivers in' . $delivery;
        ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the URL for the form page? If it starts with `file:///`, you're not loading your page via XAMPP and the PHP is not getting parsed

Comment: Try to print the `$_POST` array.

Comment: @phil. Thanks for the answer. I was not running the file on the local host. Solved